# Is it possible make MediaWiki refer to each page by type and id number?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am currently trying to create a website that uses MediaWiki which will have certain articles that will have the same exact name as another or others, such as John Smiths (this mainly includes names of people among other things).

I wanted to know if it was possible for me to separate each kind of page (User pages, Multimedia pages, normal pages/articles, etc) in the pages table so that I could make MediaWiki refer by default to each kind of page separately and by their id number (especially in the url), and the User Pages so that they refer to the User id number instead of its page_id.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page names have to be unique. There's no way to go around that. One reason for this is because one has to handle links (Such as [[Gaius Julius Caesar]], what should it refer to in your example?).

Having said that, one could do something like

- Save each page under an ugly, auto-generated name, such as id0 up to id9999 etc.
- Write or search for an extension/skin that lets you change a page's appearance such that the "title" of the page is not the actual title of the page (because the actual title is `id1234` or something, you don't want that to appear anywhere.)

Links can now be done like [[id1234|Gaius Julius Caesar]] etc, and links like [[Gaius Julius Caesar]] are all red.

However, this might be considered a "hack", and it might be inconvenient in the long run if your entire wiki is somewhat "hacky". I advise you to think about *why* you want several pages with the exact same name, and if there really is no other solution (Such as auto-generated identifiers inside explanatory parentheses, e.g. `Gaius Julius Caesar (1)`, `Gaius Julius Caesar (2)` etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the response! The problem with just renaming everything as an id, is that now I don't have a name attached to the article, so if I was requesting for article id number 1234, I would expect a page with the name Gaius Julius Caesar to show up, not one titled with an id, and instead have that be the url. I was discussing this with other people on the MediaWiki site and came to the conclusion that the easiest way is probably creating an extension or something and add fields for page type and type id in the page table. And also I have completely made up my mind for using several pages

Comment: I don't really understand how you are going to handle several pages with the exact same name. This is simply not possible, the assumption that page names are unique is hard-coded in many parts of mediawiki and its extensions. Before you try to find a way to retrieve pages by id, I think you should clarify how you want that to work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that does certainly put a perspective on things. The best thing that I could think of currently now that you said what you said is that I could still create a field for identifying for which type of page each page is. In that way I could go on with just doing, as you said, the page name plus a (1), (2), etc, and an id number for that specific page type, and then later on if I want I could create an entire system from scratch and import them into there and work from there. But for now I'll just do as you suggested. Again thank you for your help